How do I determine the cause of an "Unknown instruction error"?
I don't know why i cannot move my grass token from Phantom to ByBit wallet, when i do it show me this problem:
Program Error: "Instruction #4 Failed - Unknown instruction error"

It is not about fee( Maybe the token has problem or Phantom has problem idk). My transaction: https://solscan.io/tx/RNkzXiaXyZn6jozq8R22WwK6qWwAT6kY9GBVgTP2TRo4GtpySeYAhr89GBigkxMQeYeu9wjDZBpDHxaPxn8gses

This is probably a duplicate question but I couldn't find an existing answer.
> Instruction #4 Failed - Unknown instruction error"

Solana transactions have many steps, called instructions. Instruction 4 of your transaction failed.
Let's look at your transaction on Solana Explorer:
Scroll down to the bottom you can see the logs:
4. Associated Token Program Instruction

> Program invoked: System Program
  > Transfer: insufficient lamports 895600, need 2039280
  > Program returned error: "custom program error: 0x1"

You need more lamports (the minor unit of SOL) in the account.

